# Extracting Terrain Shadow of an Entity in CesiumJS

Tags: shadow, cesiumjs

I want to extract one entity’s shadow on the terrain. Is there any possibility to have access to shadow points or their pixels positions for an entity?
What I want is the position of the boundary of shadow on the terrain for an entity.

I would be really thankful if sb could help.

Thanks!